# Usage of "where ... and where ..." is acceptable?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am writing a statistical paper and I am trying to define two objects in the same sentence. My sentence is something like this:

> The response is represented by Y = (Y_1, ..., Y_n), **where** 'Y_n = (y_n1,..., y_nj)' is [ explanation of Y_n ] **and where** y_nj is [ explanation of y_nj ]

I would like to know if it is acceptable to use the term "where" and "and where" in the way I used above.
Or there is a better way of expressing the same idea with other words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. It's best without the repetition:

> The response is represented by Y = (Y_1, ..., Y_n), **where** 'Y_n = (y_n1,..., y_nj)' is [ explanation of Y_n ] **and** y_nj is [ explanation of y_nj ]

You already stated "where" in front so no need to repeat it.